# Update charts in chartjs and angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, ngrx

I have the problem with update chart js in angular. I am using for it ngrx store.

In selector subscriber (run in ngOnInit) I tried update the chart data:

```
this.yrSubscription = this.userDataStore.pipe(select(selectYrReport))
  .subscribe(el => {
    el.sessions.forEach(item => {
      this.datasetsSessions[0].data.push(+item);
    });
  });
```

And my chart data:

```
datasetsSessions: ChartDataSets[] = [{
  label: 'Sessions',
  data: [],
  fill: false
}];
```

Register charts:

```
private _registerCustomChartJSPlugin(): void {
  (window as any).Chart.plugins.register({
    afterDatasetsDraw: (chart, easing): any => {
      if (!chart.options.plugins.xLabelsOnTop
        || (chart.options.plugins.xLabelsOnTop && chart.options.plugins.xLabelsOnTop.active === false)) {
        return;
      }

      const ctx = chart.ctx;

      chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i): any => {
        const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);
        if (!meta.hidden) {
          meta.data.forEach((element, index): any => {
            // Draw the text in black, with the specified font
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
            const fontSize = 13;
            const fontStyle = 'normal';
            const fontFamily = 'Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial';
            ctx.font = (window as any).Chart.helpers.fontString(fontSize, fontStyle, fontFamily);

            const dataString = dataset.data[index].toString() + 'k';

            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            const padding = 15;
            const startY = 24;
            const position = element.tooltipPosition();
            ctx.fillText(dataString, position.x, startY);

            ctx.save();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.setLineDash([5, 3]);
            ctx.moveTo(position.x, startY + padding);
            ctx.lineTo(position.x, position.y - padding);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.12)';
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.restore();
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

And I call it in constructor.

I know, that I need run chart.update(). But still I have got an error about chart is undefined etc.

Comment: run in ngoninit

Comment: A yes, I run it in ngoninit. I am sorry for missing that information. The main problem with chart.update(); still have problem with undefined.

Comment: can you give a stackblitz?

Comment: and why you don't have ctx in register?

Comment: first parameter is generally ctx?

Comment: you are not assigning Chart.plugins.register to your global variable chart why?

Comment: you are also getting initial data from ngrx store?

Comment: Need more info about your problem.In which function you are calling `chart.update()`? In which function you are initializing the chart? Registering a chart js plugin and initializing a chart are two different processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ng2-charts`, there's no need to invoke `chart.update()`, let Angular change detection do its job. In case it doesn't work as expected, reassign the `data` array after pushing a new value to it. This can be done using [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) as shown below.

```
this.yrSubscription = this.userDataStore.pipe(select(selectYrReport))
  .subscribe(el => {
    el.sessions.forEach(item => {
      this.datasetsSessions[0].data.push(+item);
      this.datasetsSessions[0].data = this.datasetsSessions[0].data.slice();
    });
  });
```

But the main issue is probably located in the `_registerCustomChartJSPlugin` method. Instead of defining such a method, define its content in a `chartPlugins` variable as follows:

```
chartPlugins = [{
  afterDatasetsDraw: (chart, easing): any => {
    ...
  }
}];
```

Inside the HTML template, you then have to provide `chartPlugins` as follows.

```
<canvas baseChart
  [datasets]="datasetsSessions"
  [plugins]="chartPlugins"
  ...
</canvas>
```

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-plugin-and-updating?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are registering the charts in the same component . First of all you need to keep a reference to your custom chart. In your component add this in your component class

```
customChartInstance : Chart;
```

Then in your `afterDatasetsDraw` add 
`this.customChartInstance=chart`

then in your subscription add

```
 this.chart.update();
```

Answer (score -3):

Above Component Decorator have this :-

```
var require: any;
var Chart = require('chart.js');
```

In component have a property for keeping instance of chart

```
public chart: Chart;
```

First you need to understand is that Chart.plugins.register will only register a plugin globally for all charts.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#global-plugins

You need a chart for this plugin to apply

Lets Say you have a Canvas in your HTML like :-

```
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

You need to update your inside ngoninit to ngrx Subscription To create a new chart if its not available.

```
ngOnInit() {
this._registerCustomChartJSPlugin();
this.yrSubscription = this.userDataStore.pipe(select(selectYrReport))
  .subscribe(el => {
      if(!this.chart) {
        this.createChart();
      }
    el.sessions.forEach(item => {
      this.datasetsSessions[0].data.push(+item);
    });
    this.chart.update();
  });
}
public createChart() {
   this.chart = new Chart('canvas'); //Include if any object required as second Parameter
}
```

Comment: No - it is not correct. Charts are working properly, only problem with update. I think should be use beforeUpdate API etc. But I have problem with that.

Comment: Where you are creating chart, in other component? Can you give it's selector? Or if its in this component, can you share the html? Plus register statement can't be wrong. As i gave it from official doc. Please open that link i gave