# Using a function in ng2 Charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

Hi I am currently trying to get a simple function working in ng2 Charts.

my Function:

```
  changeFontColor(){
    let change = this.lineChartOptions.legend.labels.fontColor = "red";
    return change;
  };
```

and my lineChartOptions:

```
public lineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend:{
    onHover: this.changeFontColor,
     labels: {
      boxWidth: 10, 
      padding: 20,
    
      fontSize: 15,
      fontFamily: "new Times Roman",
      fontStyle: "bold",
      fontColor: "grey",
  };
```

but i dont know why its not working the console says that `lineChartOptions` is undefined but i don't get any red underscores and dont know how to fix it.

Comment: can you possibly provide runnable code (i.e. StackBlitz)?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uop8dm?file=package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the `onHover` callback function as follows:

```
onHover: () => this.changeFontColor(),
```

The `changeFontColor` method would also have to be changed. Please note that I reassign `lineChartOptions` with a copy of itself to make Angular change detection work.

```
changeFontColor(): void {
  this.lineChartOptions.legend.labels.fontColor = "red";
  this.lineChartOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lineChartOptions));
};
```

Please take a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cgmayf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: thank you that helped me a lot but i have one more question. The `this.lineChartOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lineChartOptions));` part is that only there for angular to read the directory ?

Comment: @gamble: I reassign `lineChartOptions` to make sure, the chart is updated with the new configuration (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62243736/2358409)